# Fundamental Identities on Exponents

Tags: linear-algebra, exponential-function, exponential-distribution, exponential-sum

I came across some properties of "Exponential and Logarithmic Equations and Inequalities" in the book "*Problems in Mathematics*" by *V GOVOROV*. The problem which I am facing is of one of the properties in it.

The property given in book goes like this:

> *$a^x \cdot b^x = (a\cdot b)^x, b>0$*

I understand the meaning of the first part of property but what is the need of condition "b>0" in the property. The property still holds true if assumed "$a=2; b=-3; x=4$"

$$(2)^4 \cdot (-3)^4 = (16) \cdot (81) = 1296$$

$$(2)^4 \cdot (-3)^4 = ({2\cdot-3})^4 = (-6)^4 = 1296$$

So **why** is the condition "$b>0$" **required**?

Comment: What if $a < 0$ and $b < 0$ and $x = \frac 12$?

Comment: It is unclear to me why there is not also a condition $a>0$. The condition clearly has to do with the exponentiation being well defined and satisfying $a^x=\exp(x\ln a)$, and the condition that the base ($a$) is a positive real number ensures this. It beats me why the condition is only imposed for $b$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in general $b^x$ only makes sense if $b\geq0$. There are a few exponents that work for negative numbers, namely integer powers. But in general one defines $b^x=e^{x\log b}$, which requires $b>0$. There is no natural meaning for something like $(-2)^{0.7}$.

Answer (score 1):

the condition is necessary when x is not an integer but a fraction or decimal
for eg. Take $a=1, b=-1, x=0.1234$
now the result would be $$1^{0.1234}.(-1)^{0.1234}=(-1)^{0.1234}$$
which is undefined in real numbers hence the condition holds.
I think the condition may be $ab \gt 0$